# how to join N vectors into matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, join, vector

I tried looking this up, but don't really know what to look for...

I need to "table-join" N vectors, meaning, 
to create a matrix in which every input vector has a row, and every possible entry has a column.

Also it would be nice to have a translation vector to has easy access to which column is responsible for which entry

for example

```
a = [3, 2, 4, 9]
b = [3, 1, 5, 9]
c = [2, 4, 9, 6]
```

then

```
join(a, b, c) =
[
3;    2;   nan; 4;   nan; 9; nan,
3;    nan; 1;   nan; 5;   9; nan,
nan;  2;   nan; 4;   nan; 9; 6,
]
```

with a translation vector

```
[3,2,1,4,5,9,6]
```

so if I find out something about the i'th column, I can easily know what that column represents.

I prefer the join operation to be able to take in n vectors (they can be of the same length), but 2 is also ok.

Also, on a second glance, this data representation seems a bit redundant at some points. Perhaps there is a better way to even represent the "join-matrix"

Thanks

Comment: your example makes no sense, where does the `nans` come from? Also have you read about `tables` http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html

Comment: @GameOfThrows since each row represents an input vector, and each colums represents a value, if a value does not exist in an input vector, it is nan. I have read about tables, but prefer a pure vector solution if possible.

Comment: You mean translation vector is `[3,2,1,4,5,9,6]` ?

Comment: That still makes no sense, take a for example, [3,2,4,9] and b [3,1,5,9] the join of those would be [3,9] because they both have 3 and 9 common. What join are you talking about

Comment: I named this "join". you are talking about something else which is mathematical join i assume. Please read again, and take my "join" as "someMagicFunction"

Comment: Are the values guaranteed to be in the same position? e.g. with the given sample vectors, if there's a `3` in the vector it'll be in the first position?

Comment: urg, I think it is just an `ismember` question

Comment: @excaza no, as the example shows about the value 2

Comment: I asked *if* the vector has a 3, will it be in the first position

Comment: @excaza no. the values are arbitrary.

Comment: So `c` could be `[4, 9, 6, 3]`?

Comment: @excaza [4,9,6,2] you mean? then yes. it can't have 3

Comment: No, I said what I meant.

Comment: @excaza it's an input it can be anyting, but it wouldn't benefit the question... for this output, the order in c doesn't matter, but the values do

Comment: It absolutely does matter. If the order can be *anything* then you need an additional rule to determine how the translation vector is generated, because assuming 3 is always to the left of 2 now does not make sense.

Comment: @excaza yes, you are correct.

Comment: @excaza Please explain. the answer below uses unique, and then ismember. where is the ordering taken into account here?

Comment: By using `unique`, you are asserting that the order of your translation vector is the order that your values *first* appear in your concatenated vectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you want to construct your translation vector using all the possible unique inputs in the order that they were received. To do this, we can concatenate all of the inputs together than find the unique values.

```
values = cat(1, [3, 2, 4, 9], [3, 1, 5, 9], [2, 4, 9, 6])
%//  3     2     4     9
%//  3     1     5     9
%//  2     4     9     6


translationVector = unique(values, 'stable')
%//  3     2     1     4     5     9     6
```

Then we want to use `ismember` to return a logical array for any given input to specify which values of our translation vector are present in the input argument.

```
columns = ismember(translationVector, [3 2 4 9])
%//  1     1     0     1     0     1     0
```

We then want to set just those columns in the output matrix.

```
output(1, columns) = [3 2 4 9];

%//   3     2   NaN     4   NaN     9   NaN
%// NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
%// NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

We then repeat this for all of your input arrays.

## Implementation

Here is some code that accomplishes that.

```
function [out, translationVector] = yourjoin(varargin)

    %// Make sure all inputs are row vectors
    varargin = cellfun(@(x)x(:).', varargin, 'uni', 0);   %'

    %// compute the translation vector
    translationVector = unique(cat(1, varargin{:}), 'stable');

    %// Pre-allocate your matrix of NaNs
    out = nan(numel(varargin), numel(translationVector));

    %// Fill in each row using each input argument
    for k = 1:numel(varargin)
        %// Identify columns that we have
        toreplace = ismember(translationVector, varargin{k});

        %// Set the values of those columns to the input values
        out(k,toreplace) = varargin{k};
    end
end
```

And then as a test:

```
a = [3 2 4 9];
b = [3 1 5 9];
c = [2 4 9 6];

D = yourjoin(a,b,c)

     3     2   NaN     4   NaN     9   NaN
     3   NaN     1   NaN     5     9   NaN
   NaN     2   NaN     4   NaN     9     6
```

Comment: yeah...in the middle of writing `ismember`; well, I misunderstood the question first because he wrote the translation vector wrong.

Comment: @Suever maybe add `transvec` as a second output

Comment: @Dan Thanks for the recommendation. Added.